# Is there a function or simple code in c++ that does the same as int.to_bytes()?

Tags: c++, integer, byte, converters

I just started my first c++ project. Its a simple project, I want to convert an integer to bytes. So I was wondering if there is any function or simple code in c++ that does the same as `int.to_bytes(integer, size, byteorder="little")` in python.

Comment: `memcpy(bytes, integer, sizeof(integer)`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about endianness you can do something like

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<unsigned char> intToBytes(int paramInt)
{
     vector<unsigned char> arrayOfByte(4);
     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
         arrayOfByte[3 - i] = (paramInt >> (i * 8));
     return arrayOfByte;
}
```